# No Application Access Policy found for this app

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, postman

I am getting my access token with : [get access token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0S9Z.png).

With this token I am trying to create a meeting with [request with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCFDQ.png).

I am using azure AD, where I created an app and granted some access [rights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mybKf.png).

What else should I configure to allow a User of my app to create a meeting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an application access policy for this to work:

See Microsoft documentation below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/cloud-communication-online-meeting-application-access-policy

Comment: You are correct, however I don't really understand why I have to go through a powershell with a skype admin account to do that and not directly from azure.

Comment: I would ignore the usage of "skype" my assumption would be this is because remnants of the skype infrastructure still remains as teams was formally known as Skype for Business.