# Powershell Graph create Teams meeting/messages

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I have been doing a fair amount of investigation into creating meetings in MS Teams, or just creating a post in a channel/chat. This [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) shows that only delegated permissions are able to post a message in Teams, while [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/cloud-communication-online-meeting-application-access-policy) (which was linked to by this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71140802/no-application-access-policy-found-for-this-app)) implies that creating a meeting is only available for Skype for Business, not Teams.

I am aware Power Automate does this and I have already gotten it to work, but we are looking into PowerShell alternatives due to the fact that we want to have more control over the data input for triggering the workflow.

Has anybody had success in creating long-term automated method for using Teams with PowerShell? The end goal is to have an automated messaging system that does not require a user to authenticate.

Comment: Could you please refer below docs and let us know if it helps? **1.Send chatMessage in a channel or a chat:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=powershell#example-1-send-a-hello-world-message-in-a-channel **2.Create onlineMeeting:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=powershell#example-1-create-an-online-meeting-with-user-token

Comment: That is where I initially looked. The issue is that application permissions are only available for migration purposes. I am wondering if there is a way to send a message without a user needing to login to their personal account. The script is supposed to run on a cron job, or something similar

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any other way without user login.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no other way to send a message without a user needing to login to their personal account.